# RecyclerView Hangs while scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-scrollview

I am creating a forum app. It has homepage like Facebook's Home Page. It contains posts which has videos and images. While I scroll my page it hangs a lot. I want to know how can I make it smooth as Facebook's Homepage. Please help.

Adapter Code:

public class PostListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public CardView cardView;

Context context;
List<StoriesDatum> storiesDatumList;
StoriesDatum storiesDatum;

FragmentHome fragmentHome;

boolean isPressed;
public static ImageView ivFav;


SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
String videoURL = "http://blueappsoftware.in/layout_design_android_blog.mp4";

int qty;

View itemView;

public PostListAdapter(Context context, List<StoriesDatum> storiesDatumList, FragmentHome fragmentHome) {
    this.context = context;
    this.storiesDatumList = storiesDatumList;
    this.fragmentHome = fragmentHome;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);


    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    myViewHolder.layout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    myViewHolder.txtNamePosted = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNamePosted);
    myViewHolder.txtPostTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPostTitle);
    myViewHolder.ivAdd = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivAdd);
    myViewHolder.ivLike = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivLike);
    myViewHolder.ivFav = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFav);
    myViewHolder.relativeLike = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLike);
    myViewHolder.tvPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPost);
    myViewHolder.txtLike = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLike);
    myViewHolder.txtCommunityName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCommunityName);
    myViewHolder.ivImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    myViewHolder.txtComment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtComment);
    myViewHolder.txtTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
    myViewHolder.txtCommentCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCommentCount);
    myViewHolder.txtLikeCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLikeCount);
    myViewHolder.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    myViewHolder.ivPost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPost);
    myViewHolder.exoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exo_player_view);

    storiesDatum = storiesDatumList.get(position);

    holder.txtCommunityName.setText(storiesDatum.getComTitle());
    holder.txtPostTitle.setText(storiesDatum.getTitle());


    // TextView tvPost = new TextView(R.id.tvPost);

    String story_body = String.valueOf(storiesDatum.getStoryBody());
    String story_type = String.valueOf(storiesDatum.getStoryType());
    String story_url = String.valueOf(storiesDatum.getStoryUrl());


    if (story_type.equals("1")) {
        holder.tvPost.setText(story_body);
        holder.tvPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.ivPost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.exoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fragmentHome.makeTextViewResizable(holder.tvPost, 3, "....View More", true);

    } else if (story_type.equals("2")) {
        holder.tvPost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ivPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.exoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (story_url.startsWith("https://") || story_url.startsWith("http://")) {
            Glide.with(context).load(storiesDatum.getStoryUpload())
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.top_communities_circle)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(holder.ivPost);
        } else {
            Glide.with(context).load(Constants.image_url + storiesDatum.getStoryUpload())
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.top_communities_circle)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(holder.ivPost);
        }

        Log.e("tag", "image_url" + Constants.image_url + storiesDatum.getStoryUpload());
    } else {
        holder.tvPost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ivPost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.exoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        try {

            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
            exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);

            Uri videoURI;
            if (story_url != null) {
                videoURI = Uri.parse("http://66.42.57.85/tellit/public/uploads//157658624483.mp4");
            } else {
                videoURI = Uri.parse("http://66.42.57.85/tellit/public/uploads//157658624483.mp4");
            }


            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoURI, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

            holder.exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
            exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
            //exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainAcvtivity", " exoplayer error " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    String comm_photo = String.valueOf(storiesDatum.getComImage());

    if (comm_photo.equals(null) || comm_photo.equals("null") || comm_photo.equals("")) {
        holder.ivImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.top_communities_circle);
    } else {
        Glide.with(context).load(comm_photo)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.top_communities_circle)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(holder.ivImage);
    }
    holder.txtNamePosted.setText("Posted by " + storiesDatum.getUsername());

    String created_date = storiesDatum.getCreatedAt();

    //call date
    String corecDate = fragmentHome.createDate(created_date);
    holder.txtTime.setText(corecDate);

    holder.txtCommentCount.setText(storiesDatum.getCommentsCount() + " Comments");
    holder.txtLikeCount.setText(storiesDatum.getStoryemojiCount() + " Reactions");


    holder.txtCommunityName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            storiesDatum = storiesDatumList.get(position);
            fragmentHome.sendToCommunityPage(storiesDatum.getUserId(), storiesDatum.getComTitle(), storiesDatum.getCommunityId(), storiesDatum.getCommunity().getDescription(), storiesDatum.getComImage());
        }
    });
    holder.txtNamePosted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            storiesDatum = storiesDatumList.get(position);
            fragmentHome.sendToUserProfile(storiesDatum.getUserId(), storiesDatum.getUsername());
        }
    });

    holder.ivAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            storiesDatum = storiesDatumList.get(position);
            fragmentHome.addCommunity(storiesDatum.getCommunityId());
        }
    });

    holder.relativeLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupWindow popupwindow_obj = popupDisplay(holder);
            int currentapiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Log.e("tag", "checked123");
                popupwindow_obj.showAsDropDown(holder.txtPostTitle, -10, -15);

            } else {
                Log.e("tag", "checked1233456");
                popupwindow_obj.showAsDropDown(holder.txtPostTitle, 0, 10);
            }


        }
    });
    Log.e("tag", "jpined_favourite" + storiesDatum.getJoined() + storiesDatum.getFav());
    if (storiesDatum.getJoined() == 0) {
        holder.ivAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.ivAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (storiesDatum.getFav() == 1) {

        holder.ivFav.setImageResource(R.mipmap.mark_as_favorite_filled);
    } else {


        holder.ivFav.setImageResource(R.mipmap.mark_favorite);
    }


    holder.txtComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentHome.openCommentbox();
        }
    });

    holder.ivFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            storiesDatum = storiesDatumList.get(position);

            if (storiesDatum.getFav() == 0) {
                fragmentHome.addFavt(storiesDatum.getCommunityId().toString(), "markfav");
            } else {
                fragmentHome.addFavt(storiesDatum.getCommunityId().toString(), "unmarkfav");
            }
        }
    });

    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentHome.sendToSinglePost();
        }
    });

}

// call this method when required to show popup

public PopupWindow popupDisplay(final PostListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder) {

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(context);

    // inflate your layout or dynamically add view
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_emoji, null);

    ImageView imgAdvice = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgAdvice);
    ImageView imgLove = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgLove);
    ImageView imgBrokenHeart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgBrokenHeart);
    ImageView imgEpic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgEpic);
    ImageView imgFunny = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgFunny);


    ImageView imgHealMe = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgHealMe);
    ImageView imgHearU = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgHearU);
    ImageView imgMeToo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMeToo);
    ImageView imgNoEgo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgNoEgo);
    ImageView imgRedFlag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgRedFlag);
    ImageView imgSolidarity = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgSolidarity);
    ImageView imgTruth = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTruth);
    ImageView imgYellowFlag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgYellowFlag);
    ImageView imgTellMore = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTellMore);


    imgAdvice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.advice);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Advice");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgLove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.love);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Love");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgBrokenHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.broken_heart);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Broken Heart");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgEpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.epic);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Epic");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgFunny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.funny);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Funny");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });


    imgAdvice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.advice);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Advice");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgHealMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heal_me);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Heal Me");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgHearU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.hear_you);
            holder.txtLike.setText("I Hear You");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgMeToo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.me_too);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Me Too");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgNoEgo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.no_ego);
            holder.txtLike.setText("No Ego");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });


    imgRedFlag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.red_flag);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Red Flag");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgSolidarity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.solidarity);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Solidarity");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgTruth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.truth);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Truth");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgYellowFlag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.yellow_flag);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Yellow Flag");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    imgTellMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.mipmap.tellmore);
            holder.txtLike.setText("Tell More");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setContentView(view);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    return popupWindow;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return storiesDatumList.size();
}

private static class ViewHolder {


}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtNamePosted, txtCommunityName, txtPostTitle, tvPost, txtLike, txtComment, txtTime, txtCommentCount, txtLikeCount;
    Button btnPay;
    RelativeLayout layout, relativeLike, relativeLayout;
    LinearLayout linear;
    ImageView ivAdd, ivImage, ivLike, ivFav, ivPost;
    SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView;
    ;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


    }
}
```

}

Call Adapter via Fragment :

```
          JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                            if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {

                                list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                txtNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                List<StoriesDatum> datumArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                                datumArrayList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), StoriesDatum[].class));
                                final PostListAdapter postListAdapter = new PostListAdapter(getActivity(), datumArrayList, FragmentHome.this);
                                RecyclerView.LayoutManager LayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                                list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                                list.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager1);


                                // set elements to adapter
                                list.setAdapter(postListAdapter);


                            }
```

I am not sure how can I make it smooth scrollable. Please help. My page contains only 15 items.

Comment: As a general rule don't initialize i.e. use `new` in your `onBindViewHolder()` method. This method gets called a lot, infact whenever you are scrolling. Also you might want to divide your `story_type` into different `ViewHolder`s by overriding [getItemViewtype()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)).

Comment: Your adapter is terrible, it's too much code and logic, that is not good. I think that is why scroll not smooth

Answer (score 3):

Your adapter is really, really heavy, especially `onBindViewHolder` method.

Few tips:

- You can't keep heavy reference to fragment in adapter (remove `FragmentHome` and use interface instead),
- In every `ViewHolder` you create new instance of heavy `ExoPlayer`, you should delegate playing video to new screen,
- Adapter is full of logic. Read about MVP or MVVM design patterns and SOLID principles. Adapter should be only responsible for displaying list, nothing more. Also consider making multiple ViewHolders for specific cases to avoid additional `ViewHolder` logic.

Answer (score 1):

Add nestedScrollingEnabled false for recycle view
->> android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

Example

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_home_"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: In RecyclerView, I used it normally, but in NestedScrowView there was a problem. See your specific case. Do not use android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" in NestedScrollView. There is an error when initializing the Activity. In this case, use it in the Activity or Fragment code. In Java: scrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);